# Ionic navbar issue

Tags: html, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a problem displaying an icon in the navbar. It is displaying correctly in the browser when using `ionic serve`, and also in `ionic serve --lab` as well as on my phone. However, on client's phone, it's misplaced...

**On phone:**

[image]

**In browser:**

[image]

The code `index.html`:

```
<ion-nav-bar class="bar-dark" align-title="center" ng-controller="navBarCtrl">

    <ion-nav-buttons>
        <a class="button button-icon icon ion-home" ng-href="#/category"></a>
    </ion-nav-buttons>

    <ion-nav-buttons side="secondary">
        <div ng-include="" src="'templates/partials/navigation.html'"></div>
    </ion-nav-buttons>

</ion-nav-bar>
```

The code `navigation.html`:

```
<div>
    <a class="button button-icon icon ion-android-cart" ng-href="#/cart">
        <span class="badge badge-assertive">{{item.count}}</span>
    </a>
    <button class="button button-icon icon ion-android-more-vertical" ng-click="showActionsheet()"></button>
</div>
```

Comment: seems like a device specific issue. You should get your hands on a similar device and debug the issue there. Or you could try with something like Genymotion (if its android) and see if you can replicate the issue there.

Comment: @Norgul - Check this codepen https://codepen.io/calendee/pen/hIkoJ

Comment: @Norgul - https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/930

Comment: @Norgul - https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/384